# Mobile app (html5/javascript) communicate with Google App Engine example

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

I'm building a mobile app (html5/javascript + PhoneGap) with GAE as backend server (Java). After a few days' research still couldn't get the whole picture.

Is there a open source example of such configuration on communication part? Mainly OAuth, send/receive data from mobile client, user Channel API, push notification etc.

All examples in GAE is for web app but not for external mobile client I think. That's why it's quite different.

I learned somewhere XMLHttpRequest doesn't support cross domain communication, so I should not use that?

jQuery.ajax() seems could work for my requirements? Again, a open source example project could help me a lot!

Any links/suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: If your mobile client is html5 and javascript, it _is_ a webapp. What do you find to be deficient in the existing examples?

Comment: The samples assumes webapp is in same domain as GAE. For mobile app that is not the case.

Comment: You could setup a restful framework such as jersey on app engine.

Comment: `jQuery.ajax() == XMLHttpRequest`. I'm the one who answered your other question. You should test using the local app engine devserver, you shouldn't deploy every time you change your code.

Comment: Why would the domain be any different for a mobile app? The only difference is that you're using a mobile browser instead of a desktop one.

Comment: @TravisWebb Actually `jQuery.ajax` is capable of making cross-domain jsonp (script tag based) requests, too

Comment: Hi @TravisWebb , thanks! I did read in a javascript book that XMLHttpRequest is not capable to make cross domain request.

Comment: @NickJohnson , I think the difference is that the web app has the same domain as GAE servlet. eg:
request from myapp.appspot.com/request.js
but mobile app is a local request.js file that I upload with PhoneGap to App Store and installed to a user's iPhone locally, so that makes it cross domain. Correct?

Comment: @EthanLong I'm not familiar with how phonegap works; possibly that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a open source example of such configuration on communication part?

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

or, investigate further the jquery ajax call...

```
function uploadPicture() {

  // blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form/
  // 

  var form_data = new FormData();      // Creating object of FormData class
  var file_data = photo.src;   // Getting the properties of file from file field
  // form_data.append("file", file_data);  // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
  // var blob = new Blob([file_data], {type: 'image/png'});
  // form_data.append("file", blob)

  var dataURI = photo.src;

  alert(dataURI);

  form_data.append("file", dataURItoBlob(dataURI));

  form_data.append("field1", "stuff1");     // Adding extra parameters to form_data
  alert(JSON.stringify(form_data));

  $.ajax({
      url: serverURL,
      dataType: 'json',    // the format of the response
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,  // the format of data being sent to the server as part of request
      //                      shazwazza.com/post/Uploading-files-and-JSON-data-in-the-same-request-with-Angular-JS
      //                      setting the Content-type to 'false' will force the request to automatically
      //                      populate the headers properly including the boundary parameter.
      // stackoverflow.com/questions/2845459/jquery-how-to-make-post-use-contenttype-application-json
      // contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
      // contentType:"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
      processData: false,    // do not convert outgoing data to a string
      data: form_data,       // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data) {
                alert("success! data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                }
  });
```

Comment: thanks! but how were you able to insert the <cr><lf>? I could not make that happen.

Comment: your edit makes sense and I think I know how to do it in the future; but is there anything I need to do to "accept" your edit?